# I want to resort an array's values in descending order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I order the below array by values and in descending order?

```
Array
(
    [BASE_PRICE] => Array
        (
            [APPLE] => 0.52
            [ORANGE] => 0.91
            [BANANA] => 0.69
            [LIME] => 0.25
        )

    [MARKUP] => Array
        (
            [APPLE] => 0.20
            [ORANGE] => 0.12
            [BANANA] => 0.25
            [LIME] => 0.25
        )

)
```

The end result would need to look like the following.

```
Array
(
    [BASE_PRICE] => Array
        (
           [ORANGE] => 0.91
           [BANANA] => 0.69
           [APPLE] => 0.52
           [LIME] => 0.25
        )

    [MARKUP] => Array
        (
            [BANANA] => 0.25
            [LIME] => 0.25
            [APPLE] => 0.20
            [ORANGE] => 0.12
        )

)
```

Can I use the `arsort()` function or similar to sort the values in the array?

Comment: As a hint you can look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data is in `$data` variable

```
arsort($data['BASE_PRICE'], SORT_NUMERIC);
arsort($data['MARKUP'], SORT_NUMERIC);
```

And you are done.